# PHP ini sessions.save neither lifetime are not working

Tags: php, session

**Original issue**

session override in .htaccess, and even php ini_set not working - I made and changed .php INI settings file , I changed the lifetime to 60 seconds and changed the `session.gc_divisor 1 1` to 1 , along with `session.gc_probability 1 1` (which worked as I  chcked doing phpinfo() ) - After 60-ish seconds I refreshed the browser and was logged out....I put then put 3600000 seconds - I was logged out as usual.... approx 10 minutes of being idle after logging in.

session.cookie_lifetime 0 0

session.cookie_path / /

session.cookie_secure Off Off

session.entropy_file /dev/urandom /dev/urandom

session.entropy_length 32 32

session.gc_divisor 1 1

session.gc_maxlifetime 3600000 3600000

session.gc_probability 1 1

session.save.path /tmp

---

I attempted to change the save path to a local hard disk **(in .htaccess)**... as suggested by a user.

> Unknown: session_start():
>   open(D:\sessions/sess_1l1en5ku2n57aeoo6mvsso9oh6, O_RDWR) failed: No
>   such file or directory

also second error

> Failed to write session data (files).

All I am wanting to achieve is be able to stay logged in for a long long period of time - **even if idle** - of of course if the browser is closed...then I will be logged out

`echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` outputs:

> /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage24/fo/cu/s_/focus.uk.com/public_html

Comment: The path should point to an exististing folder on the disk. Please add the output of `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`. Where have you actually created the session folder?

Comment: I created the folder named sessions on my local disk

Comment: the result of that echo was - /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage24/fo/cu/s_/focus.uk.com/public_html

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone the current save path is set to /tmp according to phpinfo()- which I am unable to change yet I can change the session lifetime etc in the .ini file I made

Comment: Please add the recent entries of the  error.log file. It should be found in your FTP space.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone  In my FTP space there is no error.log file, similarly, there was no php.ini file till I created one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a folder within your FTP space of your hoster. According to your comments this should be located at `/websites/123reg/LinuxPackage24/fo/cu/s_/focus.uk.com`. If you cannot write to that home folder, you need to create a folder within the document root folder `/websites/123reg/LinuxPackage24/fo/cu/s_/focus.uk.com/public_html` and ensure you deny web access via `.htaccess`.

Configure the `session.save_path` setting to your own created folder. Within the PHP scripts it would be e.g.:

```
session_save_path(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '../sessions'));
```

or

```
ini_set('session.save_path', realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '../sessions'));
```

or, if within the public folder, just

```
session_save_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sessions');
```

or

```
ini_set('session.save_path', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sessions');
```

Ensure as well that PHP has write permissions to that folder. In the worst case you need to make it world-writable on shared hosting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190066/discussion-between-quasimodos-clone-and-george-richardson).